# Why is my garage door opener's belt coming off the pulley?

Tags: repair

I have a chamberlain belt drive garage door opener. The belt, for a second time in as many days, has twisted and gotten bound up around the edges of the pulley. Chamberlain is sending me a new belt as the month or so "old" one has become a little frayed. What would cause a belt to come off of the pulley and bind up inside the arm that holds it?

Comment: Photos might help reveal a problem with installation. Belt-drive units are fairly foolproof, usually.

Answer (score 3):

You basically answered your own question. A belt that's worn may have uneven tension from one side to the other. This could cause it to walk up a pulley. Of course, you may have received a faulty or damaged belt.

Another possibility is that the pulley is off plane due to worn bearings or damage.

Both problems are symptoms of improper tension or extreme age. Be sure your new belt is tensioned to spec. Most are toothed and don't require much.

Comment: Asymmetric stress could also be caused if the door's runners on one side are jammed or dragging excessively in their raceway.

Comment: I don't see how. The opener is decoupled in several ways from the door. It could add load in general, but not directed load.

Comment: You're probably right - -I'm not quite clear on how this pulley drive is set up. My thought was that if one side of the door is stuck, sooner or later the door will pull out of alignment, dragging the belt with it. Guess that would be a VERY extreme situation.